# Stay awake/wakelock for a specific duration?

Tags: java, android

I need my android application to stay alive for a short specific duration.

I have a long series of updates, during which I keep the screen alive with wake looks. After that is done, there is an dialog informing of the success. Before this one is posted however I've released the wake look. Here I want the application to have a wakelock for 30s and then release it even if the user dos not click ok on the dialog. This is because I dont want to drain the mobile.

Is there an easy way to do this? That is, once I've reached a certain stage in my code I want to have a wakelock for a short duration?

Comment: Have you tried creating a Thread and putting it to sleep for 39sec and then do whatever you want?

Answer (score 0):

For any long running tasks you should use a service, and for your purpose a ForegroundService.

This comes with the requirement to have a notification visible while your service is running. You can then post a different notification once the process is complete.

This will make your processing resilient to the user stand-by'ing the phone, rotating the phone or going to another app, all of which would interrupt processing if originating in an activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)

For ease of use, I usually override IntentService which has the least amount of boiler code required to get going.

Comment: Yeah.. no. I've inherited a code base and do not have the time to change it according to some new way of doing it from google. Just dont have the time for it.

Comment: I understand your time constraints but this is the proper way to do it. You can get away with doing it some other way I'm sure, but I'm not sure what you mean "some new way of doing it from google".