# How to make my avd stay awake

Tags: android, testing, android-virtual-device, robotium

**Problem** :

I am testing android application using robotium, My Problem is screen gets off after few second if user did not interact with the app,how to keep screen always on for testing app?

**What I tried** :

- Made Stay awake on under development options of avd

I cross verified this post but it was related to development [side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121673/stay-awake-wakelock-for-a-specific-duration) where i cant modify the source of apk

**My Question** :

how to keep screen always on for avd testing app ?

Comment: You can do the same thing that you do in the device.Option is there in the setting.

Comment: @user2012 the problem in setting awake the option enables to choose stay awake while the phone is on charge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing you can instantiate a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html).

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(pm.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My wakelook");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Don't forget the permisson [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WAKE_LOCK)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Alternatively you can try the "wake lock" option in the devices development settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Window w = ((Activity)mContext).getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
                    w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON );
```